# Inputcheckbox Required field not throwing a validation

Tags: visualforce, validation, required-field

I created an `apex:inputCheckbox` and I made that checkbox required in the Visualforce page, by using `required=true`.

I filled in all the fields except this checkbox and hit save, the fields are saving without throwing the `apex:inputCheckbox` validation

Comment: See https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000JD6B for some work-arounds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not throwing an validation error because an empty checkbox explicitly ***HAS*** a value of false, so it is filled in (AKA, it's not null, which `Required=true` is checking for). You cannot use `Required=true` for checkboxes because of this.  You have a few options.

- You can write a validation rule on your object that ensures the box
  is checked
- You can write the validation into your Save method in your
  controller, and use addError to throw a an error at the user if the
  box is not checked.

Answer (score 1):

Unchecked Checkbox represents a false value, therefore it is not null. Hence its not giving error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I able to do with Validation rule on the object to ensure that checkbox is checked, you can do that by doing like this:

```
IF(fieldname__c , FALSE, TRUE)
```

Hope this help others.

Comment: You can *always* replace `IF(condition, true, false)` with simply `condition`. Always. The corollary is you can always replace `IF(condition, false, true)` with `NOT(condition)`. It's much more clear imo.

Comment: @AdrianLarson: I remembered you have said so first I tried exactly how you have described but it did not work then I have to explicitly defined.